# Qt unicode and umlauts

Tags: qt, unicode, internationalization, diacritics

Since we've converted all our source and header files to unicode, we're facing problems with german umlauts. Everything is fine in the source but QLabels and other gui components are showing umlauts garbled.

ISO-8859-1 source works fine but causes problems when switching between OSX and Windows.

Is there anything I have to set in the project file?

Environment: Qt 4.7 with Qt Creator 2.3.0 using MinGW on Windows XP SP3

[image: Example]

Comment: Looks like your output rendered isn't expecting UTF-8. You should somehow configure it to do so.

Comment: Probably your source file is UTF-8 encoded and when opening on windows it thinks it's ISO-8859 encoded?

Comment: @RedX: Qt should be abstracting all that away, so we really shouldn't have to know what *Windows* is thinking. The answer should be about Qt somehow I think.

Comment: @Kerrek ultimately it's the compiler that converts that string into bytes that chooses whether 'Ä' is Unicode'A+˝' or Unicode'Ä' or ASCII'Ä' and he can (before C++0x) only know that from the file encoding. what he can do is QString::fromUTF8 or QString::fromASCII to ensure QString uses the proper encoding when creating the string.

Comment: @RedX: You can patently see that the string is encoded as UTF-8 but displayed byte-wise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to call

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
```

just after creating the `QApplication` object. `QTextCodec::setCodecForTr` is only needed if your using `tr()`.

EDIT: This works only for Qt older than version 5. Newer Qt versions expect the source files to be converted to UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm. Please add that you need to set `QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));` if someone uses `tr()` or it won't work. I will then happily accept your answer.

Comment: To get `QByteArray::fromPercentEncoding()` and `QByteArray::fromBase64()` working with encoded non-ASCII chars I had to call `QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings()` **and** `QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale()`, first. The `LANG` environment variable was set to `en_US.UTF-8` on that system.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and decided to use only 7bit-ASCII characters in my source files and install a QTranslator that creates the umlauts.

As the application needs to be translated to other languages anyway, this seems like a good way to avoid encoding troubles.